# Usar um método de outra classe para registrar no banco usando DAO

Tags: java, mysql

Tenho que registrar dados em um banco, mas um desses dados é calculado por uma outra classe, queria saber como pegar os dados do banco e colocar eles no calculo do método e depois registrar o resultado.

**DAO**

```
package persistencia;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import lojabrinquedos.Brinquedo;
import lojabrinquedos.Cliente;
import lojabrinquedos.ClienteBrinquedo;


public class ClienteBrinquedoDAO {
    private static Connection connection;
    private static PreparedStatement st;
    private static PreparedStatement st1;
    private static ResultSet rs;
    private static ResultSet rs1;

    public static int gravaPorCliente(int idBrinquedo, int idCliente, String data, int quantidade, double valorTotal, int matricula) throws Exception {
        int ret = 0;
        ClienteBrinquedo cb = new ClienteBrinquedo();
        Brinquedo brinquedo = new Brinquedo();
        try {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO clientebrinquedo (Brinquedo_idBrinquedo, Cliente_idCliente, data, quantidade, valorTotal, Funcionario_matricula) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            String sql2 = "Select * FROM Brinquedo where idBrinquedo = ?";
            connection = GerenteDeConexao.getConnection();
            st = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            st1 = connection.prepareStatement(sql2);
            st1.setInt(1, idBrinquedo);
            rs1 = st1.executeQuery();
            if (rs1.next()) {
                brinquedo.setPreco(rs1.getInt("preco"));
                Brinquedo.setDesconto(rs1.getInt("desconto"));
            }
            st.setInt(1, idCliente);
            st.setInt(2, idBrinquedo);
            st.setString(3, data);
            st.setInt(4, quantidade);
            st.setDouble(5, cb.calculaValorTotal());
            st.setInt(6, matricula);
            ret = st.executeUpdate();
            st.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```

**Método de Calculo**

```
    public double calculaValorBrinquedo() {
        return quantidade * Brinquedo.preco;
    }

    public double converterDesconto() {
        return (100 - Brinquedo.getDesconto())/100;
    }

    public double adicionarImpostos() {
        return calculaValorBrinquedo() + (Brinquedo.preco * impostos);
    }

    public double adicionarLucro() {
        return adicionarImpostos() + (Brinquedo.preco * lucro);
    }

    public double calculaValorTotal() {
        return valorTotal = adicionarLucro() * converterDesconto();
    }
```

Tentei esse código mas ele fica apenas registrado 220.

Answer (score 1):

**Karlos**, não entendi muito bem o que você quer fazer. Porém vou tentar explicara aqui. Caso não entenda pode mandar sua dúvida novamente.

1- Não sei quais dados você quer calcular, mas disse que eles estão no banco. Então faça uma consulta no banco (na sua classe DAO) em um método que tem o retorno do tipo do dado que queira buscar.

2- Em sua classe de cálculos, chame o método da classe DAO para realizar de fato a consulta e retornar o valor que queira, exemplo:

```
int idade = dao.buscaIdade()
```

3- Em seu método de cálculo receba o valor como parâmetro,
exemplo:

```
public void calculaSalario(int idade){
   //....... cálculo aqui
}
```

4- Guarde o valor do calculo em uma variável.

5- Para registrar no banco o valor do cálculo, receba o valor como parâmetro do método na sua class DAO, exemplo:

```
public void insereValorCalculado(double salario){
   //...... sql aqui
}
```

Se ficou difícil de entender, edite a sua pergunta novamente!!
Abç!!